# How to change background color of RadToolBarDropDown on mouse over in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik

How to change background color of RadToolBarDropDown on mouse over in ASP.NET. (Only for Button background Not for items). Please tell me. Thanks..

```
  <telerik:RadToolBarDropDown Text="Take Action" ForeColor="White" CssClass="MouseOver">
  </telerik:RadToolBarDropDown>


      .MouseOver
        {
            background: blue;            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**CSS**

```
.MouseOver
{ 
    background: blue !important; 
    color:red !important; 
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:RadToolBarDropDown Text="Take Action" HoveredCssClass="MouseOver"></telerik:RadToolBarDropDown>
```

For more information please check [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/toolbar/examples/appearance/customcssclasses/defaultcs.aspx) link.

Comment: Thanks.. its working fine,But i want entire background blue. I mean in RadToolBarDropDown only text background color is changing, But i want that button entire color should be changed..

Comment: I have removed 'rtbText' class from CSS code. Can you please check again.